# Can't put data into inflated EditText :S

Tags: android

I m having a strange behaviour there. Probably something stupid but can't find out the solution

I m developing an application that displays a table (like an excel stuff) so that each row allows a user to enter values for several characteristics of an item (same characteristics for each item).

I have written an xml file for the row and, within a ListView, I inflate the file for each item. The row is basically made of several EditText and TextView.

Everything seems to work fine but when I enter data, as soon as the virtual keyboard disappears, every data I have typed before also disappear.
It seems to be a problem when inflating since when I am directly using setContentView with the XML file of my row, there is no such problem.

Any idea?

Following is the code where my XML file is inflated (it is called from the getView method of an ArrayAdapter for a ListView):

```
private View generateItemRowView(int position, ViewGroup parent){
    String itemName = itemList[position];
    LayoutInflater inflater=this.getLayoutInflater();
    View result =inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row_layout, parent, false);
    Button rowName=(Button)result.findViewById(R.id.row_item_name);
    rowName.setTag(""+position);
    rowName.setText(itemName);
    return result;      
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure "itemName" has a value? Could it be that it is a empty String?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the second row with this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

This works in my projects^^

Comment: unfortunatelly, it doesn't change anything. Maybe the problem lies in the structure of the inflated xml i.e. LinearLayout-->TableLayout. That is really weird.

Comment: Which layout do you use in your XML? Could you post your layout.xml file? After the third line you can try to get the tablelayout and dann use this variable to get acces to the Button.

Comment: It seems I don't have the 100 points reputation to answer my own question within the next 5 hours :S And it s not a problem of having access to any field. I can access them. it s just that the data I type disappear once the virtual keyboard is removed. I use first a LinearLayout as a root and then a TableLayout within it.

Answer (score 0):

afaik ListView recycles views (uses several for all data). Any data changes (as they occur or at the input end) must be stored somewhere. When required (getView call) the data (changed) must be set too.
Search for "notorious" fancy list by Mark Murphy.

Comment: ah ok. Good to know. I have the commonsware book. So I will have a look at the chapter soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found more or less the origin of the problem and changed my strategy to resolve it.

It seems `ListView` doesn't like `EditText` in its rows when inflated (at least in what I did. So I created a `LinearLayout` full of all the rows that I had previously in my `ListView`, and inserted the resulting `LinearLayout` into a `ScrollView`. Now everything is working well. Still I can't find out why it was not working the initial way I did it.